# attach image to form, reload gallery div only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How would I go about uploading an image to my form and then refresh the div containing the uploaded images as opposed to reloading the entire page and losing the previous input?

Preferably, I would like the script to upload images to a temp folder via AJAX and then use PHP to read the folder and populate the div, but how would I trigger this / relate this to the upload button without reloading the entire page?

HTML:

```
        <div class="lightBoxGallery">
            <?php

            $dir = './templates/attachments/'.$_SESSION['Holidex'].'/temp/';

            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                //mkdir($dir, 0777);
                echo "<p>No attachments yet.</p>";

            } else {

                $handle = opendir($dir);
                $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'thumbs', 'default', 'default.php');
                while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
                {
                    if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) 
                    {
                        echo    "<a href=\"".$dir."/".$file."\" title=\"".$file."\" data-gallery=\"\"><img src=\"./templates/attachments/".$_SESSION['Holidex']."/".$_GET['mod_id']."/".$file."\" style=\"height:100px; width:100px;\"></a>
                        ";
                    }
                }
                closedir($handle);

                echo "
                <!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
                <div id=\"blueimp-gallery\" class=\"blueimp-gallery\">
                    <div class=\"slides\"></div>
                    <h3 class=\"title\"></h3>
                    <a class=\"prev\">‹</a>
                    <a class=\"next\">›</a>
                    <a class=\"close\">×</a>
                    <a class=\"play-pause\"></a>
                    <ol class=\"indicator\"></ol>
                </div>          
                <script src=\"../../plugins/blueimp/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js\"></script>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.lightbox gallery -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
        <div>
            <font>Attachments (.jpg, .png, .bmp):</font>
            <input name="upload[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
            <p class="help-block">Max. filesize 5MB</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
```

Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction here, thank you.

EDIT:
I looked at Pawa Sen's approach at reloading the  only, but cant get it to work.
JS is handing over the data upon change to my ajax.php script, which is where according to Google Chrome things go to die as no response is coming back.

AJAX.php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "upload_pics") {

    // check if any attachments have been selected
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){

        // loop through each file, get name and filepath
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

            // check whether a filepath is defined
            if($tmpFilePath != ""){

                // set filenames and path
                $filePath = "./attachments/".$_SESSION['Holidex']."/temp/";
                $shortname = date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                // check whether folder exists, otherwise create
                if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
                    mkdir($filePath, 0755, true);
                }

                // resize image to max 800px
                $maxDim = 800;
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $tmpFilePath );
                if ( $width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim ) {
                    $target_filename = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $fn = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $size = getimagesize( $fn );
                    $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
                    if( $ratio > 1) {
                        $width = $maxDim;
                        $height = $maxDim/$ratio;
                    } else {
                        $width = $maxDim*$ratio;
                        $height = $maxDim;
                    }
                    $src = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $fn ) );
                    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
                    imagecopyresampled( $dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1] );
                    imagedestroy( $src );
                    imagepng( $dst, $target_filename ); // adjust format as needed
                    imagedestroy( $dst );
                }

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath.$shortname)) {

                    $files[] = $shortname;  
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$(function () {
    $("#upload").change(function () {                                           
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { action:"upload_pics",upload:$(this).val()}, // form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#lightBoxGallery").load(location.href + " #lightBoxGallery");
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: div load only jquery ajax load method EX: $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );

Comment: sorry, im not good with javascript, mind explaining a little bit how this code works? I understand you want to load ajax/test.html which handles the file uploading, but how is this triggered when adding images to the upload input?

Comment: @pawansen, I updated the code according to your suggestion but cant get it to work. Any suggestion perhaps?